# permissions popup shows at a time in xamarin.forms ios

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am facing one issue in Displaying persmissions (like Access Current location, Access Contacts, Access Phone Calls) when we are opening the app.

The Current Scenario is " In Android, If we give "Allow" or "Deny", then only the next permission Popup will display.

But in IOS, The current existing Scenario is, all the permission Popup's will come at a time. So, I want to change that displaying Permissions like in Android.

I am using the following code for iOS in AppDelegate.cs:

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
            {

                // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;

                var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(granted);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                // iOS 9 or before
                var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
                var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(allNotificationTypes, null);
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
            }

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();

            var cameraStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Camera);
                await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Camera);
                cameraStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Camera);
                if (cameraStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {

                }

                var locationStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
                await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Location);
                locationStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
                if (locationStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {

                }
```

Anyone Please help me out from this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Suggest that Runtime to Request Permissions.Don't write permission requests in one place, you can request permissions separately on different pages or where you need them.Take a look at this article.https://montemagno.com/simplified-ios-android-runtime-permissions-with/

Comment: Thanks Jiang, i code like below.

Comment: Great, remember to mark it later!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i code like below and it works:

```
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
        {

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;

            var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(granted);
                AcessPermissionsAsync();
            });
        }
        else
        {
            // iOS 9 or before
            var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
            var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(allNotificationTypes, null);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
        }

        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();


        private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task AcessPermissionsAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            //await GetPermissions();
            var cameraStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Camera);
            await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Camera);
            cameraStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Camera);
            if (cameraStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                var locationStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
                await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Location);
                locationStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
                if (locationStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {

                }
            }
            else
            {
                var locationStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
                await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Location);
                locationStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
                if (locationStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {

                }
            }

        }
       catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }


   }
```